# Why does package version creation care about installed packages in org in certain scenarios and not others?

Tags: package, unlocked-package, package-dependency

Package A is installed in Devhub

Some code is taken out of package A and a package B version is created from it (not installed)

Newest package A version is made dependent on the same package B version that was just created

All good and no issues with version creation of A or B

And then if:

Package C is dependent on Package A.

Some code is moved out of Package A and moved to Package C.

Able to create package A version.

When I try creating package C which is dependent on the package A version just created I get:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04t6R0000011Os5: The package you're installing depends on package 'B', version '1.0'. Install package 'B' in the target org before you install package 'A'.
```

(using A.B.C for simplicity purposes only)

Why it it enforcing installation of a package in the org when all I am doing is creating a version that is dependent on other versions only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify package b as an additional dependency to package c in order for everything to work correctly. All dependencies must be explicitly listed in order of dependency in order to complete a package version.

Comment: Listing package B as a dependency in project C project.json followed by the dependency to project A results in the same message:  An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04t6R0200011Os5: The package you're installing depends on package 'B', version '1.0'. Install package 'B' in the target org before you install package 'A'. Why is target org needed for version creation?  @sfdcfox

Comment: My bad. My sfdx-project json syntax was off for multiple dependencies. So basically no automatic dependency management but it needs to be listed out explicitly. Thank you as always.